# NullPointerException on java array, have created new objects

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a NullPointerException error when trying to run my program at this part:

```
File folder = new File("mypictures");
File[] pictures = folder.listFiles();
allCards = new Card[pictures.length];

for(int i=0; i < (pictures.length); i++){
    allCards[i] = new Card(new ImageIcon(pictures[i].getPath())); 
}
```

It complains on the follow line:

```
Card[] allCards = new Card[pictures.length];
```

Comment: `listFiles()` can return `null`. _"Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs."_

Comment: A `NullPointerException` occurs at runtime, not when compiling.

Comment: @ZouZou write that up as an answer!

Comment: @PeterBratton This is just the doc after all ! :)

Answer (score 5):

If `folder` does not refer to a directory, `listFiles()` will return `null`. I.e., when you attempt to call `pictures.length`, you'll fail with a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few things can go wrong in your code. 
Please use try catch and make sure that folder exists before listing files in the folder.